# Where is catalina.base system property declared in a default tomcat8 linux installation

Tags: linux, tomcat, environment-variables

Looking at some legacy code for a servlet and trying to figure out where the System.property "catalina.base" is taken from.
The servlet is deployed on a Tomcat instance running on a linux server.

```
   String tomcatLocation = System.getProperty( "catalina.base" )
```

When I run printenv on the linux box I see no reference to this variable. Tomcat is installed using

```
   sudo yum install -y tomcat8 tomcat8-webapps
```

and so will install to default location /usr/share/tomcat8. My packaged WAR is simply copied into [catalina.base]/webapps 
I figured there would be a properties file with this value set in it but I don't see it.  In fact /usr/share/tomcat8/conf/catalina.properties  also contains references to catalina.base which confuses me more.
The code clearly works and picks up the correct location so wondered where is catalina.base set up and assigned its value which equates to in my case at least to be /usr/share/tomcat8/  ?

Answer (score 1):

When running different *instances* of Tomcat with a common installation, you should define this in each of the `setenv.sh` scripts (same as for *CATALINA_OPTS* for example). When not defined, it is configured in `catalina.sh` to its default value (*CATALINA_HOME*).

Comment: thats the kicker,  I have looked for a startup.sh,  catalina.sh script and not finding any of these files.

Comment: is it repackaged in a way that it is defined in the service script itself ?

Comment: No,  the only reference to Tomcat in the installation script is to yum it onto the clean linux instance.  Next command is to copy the WAR inito webapps folder,  and presto,  it just works.  But I can't find any shell script that sets up this catalina.base property. I can accept that it is setup somewhere that I need not bother myself with but I don't like "magic" stuff like this that just works.

Comment: grep -ri catalina_base /

Comment: tried that command,  it  just hangs .  Another way to put this question is,  if I want to make the code in my servlet ...  System.getProperty( "catalina.base" )  ..... return "Hello" then how would I go about setting tomcat up so it would return that instead of " /usr/share/tomcat8/"

Comment: It doesn't hang but takes a long time as it will parse all your files. You can restrict on /etc or anything else. CATALINA_BASE should be defined in the setenv.sh script located in your instance bin directory. Create this script if necessary. If you don't want or cannot create it, just edit the script you are using to start tomcat and put the variable at this place. But this looks like a bit dirty.