# Not able to fetch ${catalina.base}, system property not working in log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, tomcat7, log4j2

Previously we had a log4j 1.x compatible xml format which was having this Rolling file appender configured-

```
<appender name="ALL" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/trw.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="4096KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %p [%t] %C{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Now I have changed it to the new log4j2.xml format where based on my research the
catalina.base becomes like so -

```
    <RollingFile name="ALL" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/trw.log"
                     filePattern="${sys:catalina.base}/logs/trw_%i.log"
                     append ="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="4096KB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

But when I run a test file which uses this logging configuration, the xml file is found and loaded and all is going well but instead of finding the system variable cataline.base
it creates a folder ${sys:catalina.base} and puts the log under it. My question is that - is this the expected behaviour ? Does log4j2.xml config try to search for the system property and if not found just creates a folder with that name ?
This config is in a web-application which runs on TomCat 7, spring 3.1 and servlet 2.5. Logs are getting generated as expected but only folder name seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found core of the problem thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859620/where-is-catalina-base-system-property-declared-in-a-default-tomcat8-linux-insta) answer.

Had the same issue with running tests using `${sys:catalina.base}` in log4j2.

The 1st problem is that your app running in tomcat while your tests running outside of it. Tomcat itself sets variable `catalina.base` from `CATALINA_BASE` on start, so log4j2 instance for tests doesn't know such variable as `catalina.base`.

The 2nd problem I figured out in my case that I put `export CATALINA_BASE="/path/to/catalina/location"` in `.bashrc` instead of `.profile`.

**SOLUTIONS**

1. set absolute path like (for example if your catalina lies in some user directory) `"/home/${env:USER}/path/to/cataina/location"`

OR

2. put `export CATALINA_BASE="/path/to/catalina/location"` in `.profile` and then you'll be able to set log4j2 property like `${env:CATALINA_BASE}`.

Comment: You can also provide default values for `${sys:catalina.base}`: either add `<Property name="catalina.base" value="."/>` to your config file or use `${sys:catalina.base:-.}`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thank you. Didn't know about this option.
P.S. But the key issue for me was to not using absolute path in log4j2 properties))